# How to type annotate a property overloading a base class attribute?

Tags: python, properties, mypy

I have an abstract base class

```
class B(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    h: HomeMadeType
```

where in one concrete class, I want `h` to be a property. How do I type annotate this?

```
class C(B):
    @property
    def h(self) -> HomeMadeType:
        HomeMadeType()
```

is obviously not enough (mypy says ‘error: Cannot override writeable attribute with read-only property  [override]’), but it shows that mypy understands properties in principle. However,

```
class D(B):
    @property
    def h(self) -> HomeMadeType:
        return HomeMadeType()

    @h.setter
    def set_h(self, value: HomeMadeType) -> None:
        pass
```

also fails with

```
error: Cannot override writeable attribute with read-only property  [override]
error: "Callable[[D], HomeMadeType]" has no attribute "setter"  [attr-defined]
```

so that support is not so clear, and

```
class E(B):
    def get_h(self) -> HomeMadeType:
        return HomeMadeType()

    def set_h(self, value: HomeMadeType) -> None:
        pass

    h = property(get_h, set_h)
```

results in ‘error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "property", base class "B" defined the type as "HomeMadeType")  [assignment]’ – so it seems like the support is specifically for the `@property` decorator, not even for property descriptors in general.

Is there a way I can overload an attribute with a property in a way that makes mypy happy?

Comment: Putting `@h.setter` on `set_h` defines a `set_h` property. It doesn't define a setter for `h`. `h` is still read-only.

Comment: (Also, silently doing nothing on attribute assignment is a bad idea.)

Comment: Silently doing nothing on attribute assignment is indeed a bad idea. For the context I'm working in, it's obviously done differently, but this felt like the shortest way to describe the type problem.

Comment: as @user2357112 noted the setter method has to be named the same as the property method i.e. `def h` ... when named correctly then mypy is happy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=984af58b6f8c5487e48d1a6aea06a0d9

Comment: @Anentropic hm, don't you have any references to *why* it is allowed? It's still not fully compatible (`del B().h` is allowed, while `del D().h` is not). In my understanding, only "full" properties with deleter defined should be considered compatible with raw attribute...

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike it seems there are various arguments here https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4125 along the lines that deleting an attribute is not compatible with static typing, so mypy should not care about missing property deleter, i.e. from typing perspective the class either has attribute or not, its value may be Optional but there is no way to type a deletable attribute